# Hadoop reducer performance bottleneck

Tags: java, hadoop, cascading, reducers

I have problem with one of my reducer in cascading job. All of my reducers (except one) finishes in more or less 4 minutes, but there is one that takes 2h to compute results. I checked and that single reducer take more or less the same quantity of map outputs:

- 3977529 - number of reduce input records for problematic reducer
- 3950478 - number of reduce input records that usual reducer in this job takes

There is no big difference but if we will compare reducer output records difference is much bigger:

- 388084339 - number of reduce output records for problematic reducer
- 4082267 - number of reduce output records that usual reducer in this job produces

What I also notice (thanks to -Xprof option) is that problematic reducer is spending almost all the time in next method:

> sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait

Problematic reducer is not spending a lot of time in GC - prior to counters.

Do you have any clues what is going on? How I can fix that issue? Maybe changing job configuration will help.

Comment: Despite the poor performance, Is the output correct ?

Comment: What is the size of the output for each reducer ? I think your problem is the amount of data that you are writing in the output. Instead to distribute your data to have a similar input in all your reducer you should distribute the reducer input to end with similar amount of data at the output. For each input you are writing several outputs instead less as usual in reducers. Then you need to implement your solution different that cases described in the internet, putting more effort to distribute the output instead the input.